# Как вывести статьи?

Tags: python, django

У меня в urls.py есть 2 адреса, первый со статьями, второй со списком всех этих статей.
Вот код:

```
path('news',views.list_news,name = 'list_news'),
path('news/<int:article_id>', views.news, name = 'news'),
```

Вот их view:

```
def news(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = News.objects.get(id = article_id)  
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')    

    return render(request,'articles/news.html',{'article': a})



def list_news(request):
    title_elements = News.objects.all()
    return render(request,'listnews.html',context = {'key_title':title_elements})
```

И в news у меня есть один шаблон в котором выводятся статьи,если в адресную строку ввести 1,то он выведет первую статью,2 - вторую и.тд И вот в списке ВСЕХ этих статей у меня выводится каждый их заголовок и кнопка для этой статьи и что мне надо будет прописать в form action = ? что бы меня пересылало к этим статьям,как бы на первой кнопке к 1 статье,на второй - ко второй статье(тоесть у меня ОДИН шаблон выводит все статьи,но к ним надо обращатся по цифрам)

Comment: покажи свой шаблон, что бы было понятно куда и какую кнопку ты хочешь добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать форму для переадресации на статью не нужно! Можно просто в контекст вашего view со списком всех статей поместить переменную articles, которая будет хранить список статей. Вот пример view:

```
def articles(request):
    articles = Model.objects.all()
    return render(request,'list.html',context={'articles':articles

}
```

И в шаблоне сделать что-то типа того:

```
{% for a in articles %}
    <a href={% url 'name' a.id %}>{{a}} - ссылка на статью</a>
{% endfor %}
```

name в ссылке - это псевдоним ссылки вашего url-a с детальным отображением статьи. к примеру вот:

```
path('list',views.articles,name='list'),
path('list/<int:article_id>',views.detail,name='detail')
```

В теге url первое мы казали адрес, куда будет вести эта ссылка, а второе это аргументы. Как видите во втором url-адресе у нас есть url-параметр article_id и так как у нас есть url-параметр нам нужно передать аргументы в теге url шаблона. a.id - в ссылку будет подставляться id каждой записи.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

(Использовать формы вместо ссылок - плохая практика, не стоит злоупотреблять этим там, где оно не требуется)

В шаблоне `listnews.html` в цикле `{% for new in key_title %}`, где вы генерируете вид списка (почему здесь нет кода этого шаблона, кстати?), вам необходимо делать ссылку кнопочки вида `{% url 'news' news.id %}`.

То есть, у вас в `path('news/<int:article_id>', ...)` есть аргумент `article_id`, и джанга его требует для генерации ссылки.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url